# Работа со списками студентов

Tags: c++, visual-studio, структуры

Нужно написать программу со списками студентов, используя списочные структуры. Также в программе должен быть файловый вводвывод информации о студентах, поиск. Подскажите, с чего начать? Также не могу понять, что такое вообще связанные списки. Если можно, пример кода. Спасибо.

Comment: смотрите в сторону STL list - контейнер списка.
<div>
<a>http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6sh2ey19.aspx</a>
</div>

Comment: Если подробнее, то: необходимо реализовать информационную систему, которая будет поддерживать работу с персональными данными студентов (просмотр, редактирование, поиск по фио, добавление\удаление), работу со списками групп (также добавление, удаление, просмотр) и файловый ввод\вывод данных о потоке. В программе должна быть система меню.

Comment: "....->prev = ->next; delete node; ... связанный список на указателях" именно так -_- помогите, кто чем сможет)

Comment: Односвязный или двусвязный? Или это не принципиально?

Comment: Односвязный лучше, думаю.

Comment: @skies, вы бы задачу свою "разжевали", как это положено. Так вероятность получения корректного ответа возрастет.

Comment: @skies, поверьте, для Вашей задачи проще получится с двусвязным. 

Если предполагается для найденного студента получать данные о группе (кроме ее номера), то советую в каждую структуру данных о студенте поместить указатель на данные о группе в списке групп.

Comment: @carapuz, std::list<T> здесь вряд ли будет лучшим выбором...хотя, это как посмотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Так как подробности задания не указаны, то я дам ответ из того, что есть. В вашем случае в самый раз могли бы подойти так называемые карты из `Standard Template Library`, а именно контейнеры `map\multimap`. Они очень удобны тогда, когда к одному конкретному значению привязан какое-либо значениезначения. В вашем случае это могут быть `Фамилия студента -> Курс`, к примеру. Но такой контейнер не может хранить дублированных ключей, а вам это может понадобиться, если к какой либо фамилии студента, например, привязано несколько значений:

```
[Фамилия] => [Курс]
[Фамилия] => [Имя]
[Фамилия] => [Возраст]
```

В таком случае в самый раз подойдет контейнер `MultiMap`. Все контейнеры STL поддерживают поиск, который вам необходим и множество других полезных функций. В принципе, вам должно быть это известно.

---

Что по поводу связных списков, то скажу, что это несложно реализовать самостоятельно.
Связный список имеет такую структуру, что каждый его элемент( кроме последнего ) указывает на следующий за ним + каждый элемент хранит некую полезную информацию. Структура немного похожа на структуру бинарного дерева, но структура последнего несколько сложнее.
**[Вот пример.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksTiXVd-6gc&feature=plcp)**

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что это учебное задание не подразумевает ни `std::list<T>`, ни `std::map<T>`, а направлено на то, чтобы человек сам реализовал классический `->prev = ->next; delete node; ...` список на указателях. Хотя, естественно, могу ошибаться.

Comment: А минус за что? Обоснуйте, пожалуйста, кто поставил.

Comment: @Asen, в Вашем примере очень мелко, но по виду структуры можно догадаться, что речь идет об односвязном списке. 

Для удаления двусвязные удобнее.

Answer (score 1):

Начать можно, думаю, с реализации непосредственно шаблонного списка для абстрактного типа Т. В Вашем случае можно сделать структуру, хранящую в себе фамилии, оценки и прочую информацию. Описываем узел списка:

```
template <class T>
class Node
{
 private:
    T data;
    Node<T> *next, *prev;
 public:
    Node(Т);
    ~Node();
};
```

Класс списка:

```
template <class T>
class List
{
 private:
    Node<T> *Head, *Tail;
 public:
    List();
    List(const List&);
    ~List();
    void View();
    void Clear();
    void AddFirst();
    void AddLast();
    void WriteToFile();
    void ReadFromFile();
    ...
};
```

Здесь реализуйте функции, необходимые Вам для работы: к примеру добавление в начало, в конец, в определенную позицию, удаление элементов, просмотр, чтение/запись в файл и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

> что такое вообще связанные списки. Если можно, пример кода.

Методичка вам в помощь: [фундаментальные структуры данных, которые могут быть положены в основу построения абстрактных данных, отображающих реальные объекты решаемой задачи](http://fpmi.ami.nstu.ru/index.php?resource=10015&amp;id_site=4).